# Beginner "while" program in C++

Tags: c++

I have to solve a problem where I calculate the salary of employees where they get 10 euros per hour for the first 40 hours and then every additional hour they get 15 euros. I have solved the problem but my console prints the answer in an endless loop and I don't know where I am wrong.

```
int hours;
double salary;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter amount of hours worked" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    while (hours <= 40)
    {
        salary = hours * 10;
        cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
    }

    while (hours > 40)
    {
        salary = (40 * 10) + (hours - 40) * 15;
        cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `if()` instead of `while()`?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using while loops like they're if statements, kind of.

Use two variables, one to take the amount of hours worked and one to start at 0 and count each hour paid.

```
int hours;
int hourscounted = 0;
double salary;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter amount of hours worked" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    while (hourscounted  <= hours)
    {
        if(hourscounted < 40)
        {
            salary = salary + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            salary = salary + 15;
        }
        hourscounted++;

    }
    cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I see how the while loop works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `while`s to `if`s.

The condition inside `while` would be always `true`, because `hours` will always be less than 40, as no modification of `hours` inside the `while` condition hence resulting in an *infinite loop*.

Modified code:

```
int hours;
double salary;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter amount of hours worked" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    if (hours <= 40)
    {
        salary = hours * 10;
        cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
    }
    else //I have removed the condition because if hours is not less than 40,
        // it has to be greater than 40!
    {
        salary = (40 * 10) + (hours - 40) * 15;
        cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

## A solution using while loops.

Since you are hell bent on getting a `while` loop solution,

Code:

```
int hours;
int counthour = 0;
double salary;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter amount of hours worked" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    while (counthour <= hours)
    {
        if(counthour <= 40)
            salary += 10;
        else
            salary += 15;
        counthour++;

    }
    cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the problem asked me to solve this with "while loop" but you are right, it makes more sense this way. I am new to programming so stuff like this aren't so obvious for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

In order for the following loop to not be infinite

```
while (hours <= 40)
{
    salary = hours * 10;
    cout << "Salary of the employee is: " << salary << endl;
}
```

Something in the loop is going to have to modify `hours` in a way that will cause `hours <= 40` to be `false`.

right now, only `salary` is getting modified in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change while to if :P And tip for future - do not use endl, unless you really need to do it. And you can have printing (cout) outside of loop/if-statement. It will never end, the while loop, it depends on something, that is not changed.

Comment: _"do not use endl,"_ Uhm, what please?

Comment: it make new line, than std::flush which force you to write to the disk, he seems to be begginer, if he do not know it, he can be suprised in future, why his program is slow, and why printf("something\n"); is way faster

Comment: Valid, but it depends solely on the context (not even taste!), further if the questioner (seemingly) doesn't know the difference between `if` and `while`, this will just confuse them and is not relevant to the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After reading your code and problem in more detail, it seems you should replace `while` by `if` to satisfy the logic you are looking at.

If your code prints in an endless loop, you should always check that why the conditions for its termination are not being met.

In your case, your loops terminate when `hours < 40` (1st case) and `hours > 40` (2nd case). You are not modifying hours in the loop, and so it is stuck in an infinite cycle.